# How to show an image in a UICollection View cell while clicking that cell in swift ios?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PlaceCollectionViewCell



    //let imageView = UIImageView()
    //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.278, green: 0.694, blue: 0.537, alpha: 1.00)

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.278, green: 0.694, blue: 0.537, alpha: 1.00).cgColor


   //cell.placeLabel.tintColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.278, green: 0.694, blue: 0.537, alpha: 1.00).cgColor

    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 40
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = true


    print("places\(indexPath.row)")
    //cell.placeLabel.text = places[indexPath.row] as! String
    cell.placeLabel.text = places[indexPath.row]
    cell.placeLabel.textColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.278, green: 0.694, blue: 0.537, alpha: 1.00)

    // code for VIew
    let view = UIView(frame: cell.bounds)
     //Set background color that you want
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.278, green: 0.694, blue: 0.537, alpha: 1.00)
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = view



    return cell
```

I have an image in collection view cell. I need to display that image only when I click the cell.Do we have to do it in cellforRowat index path?

```
//Custom class code:


  @IBOutlet weak var tickImageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var placeViewBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var placeLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
override func layoutSubviews() {

}
   override func awakeFromNib() {

    self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView.frame.size.width/2

    self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
```

Custom class code added. I want to display the ticMark image which I have declared above.

Comment: you have to use didselectrowatindexpath method

Comment: What do you mean by "I have an image in collection view cell. I need to display that image only when I click the cell."?

Comment: @NiravD Actually it's a "tickmark" image. When I click on a cell in collectionview that tickmark image should be displayed only on that cell.

Comment: @RakeshMohan Have you set multiselect mode of tableView or single select?

Comment: @RakeshMohan Make a property (May be a boolean variable) that will become true for that particular cell which will be selected. (This will be changed in didSelectItem method). Reload your collectionview cell.   Add the logic of hidden or shown imageView in cellForItemAtIndexPAth method.

Comment: @NiravD Where can I check that? Should  I make it multiselect?

Comment: @RakeshMohan No, there is no need for that i'm just asking, Are you using any custom class or struct with your collectionView datasource array?

Comment: @NiravD. I am using custom class.

Comment: @RakeshMohan Add that custom class code in your question with some little detail.

Comment: @NiravD I have added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare one instance of type `IndexPath` and maintain the cell status is it `selected` or not with it. Now use this array within `cellForItemAt indexPath` and `didSelectItemAt indexPath` like this.

```
var selectedIndexPaths = IndexPath()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PlaceCollectionViewCell
    //Your code 

    //decide weather to show tick image or not
    self.tickImageView.isHidden = self.selectedIndexPaths != indexPath
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {   
    if self.selectedIndexPaths == indexPath {
         self.selectedIndexPaths = IndexPath()
    }
    else {
         self.selectedIndexPaths = indexPath
    }
    self.tableview.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I have to show it only on the cell which I select. Now it is showing on all cells which I select.

Comment: @RakeshMohan You want at a time only one selection of cell?

Comment: Yes . I need to display that image only in the cell which I am selecting.

Comment: @RakeshMohan That also the above code do, I'm asking is you want at a time only one selected cell instead of multiple?

Comment: Exactly. That is what I require.

Comment: I am getting this error 
  Binary operator "!=" cannot be applied to be operands of type "[Indexpath]" and "indexPath"

Comment: @RakeshMohan Check the answer properly I have already change type of `selectedIndexPaths` to `IndexPath` from `[IndexPath]`

Comment: @RakeshMohan Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to read wether the tick is selected or not in cellForRow

if tick is selected {
    showImage
} else {
    hideImage
}

Then in didSelectRow
set the tick to selected or deselected
then call reloadRowForIndexPath