# Selector to get indexPath UICollectionView Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionviewcell, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to get `indexPath` on the cell when it is tapped twice.
I'm passing arguments in `Selector` like this but it is giving error.
What is the correct format for this ?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if  let subOptioncell : SubOptionsCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: subOptionsCVReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SubOptionsCollectionViewCell

          let imageNamed = "\(customizeOptionSelected[indexPath.row])"
          subOptioncell.subOptionsImage.image = UIImage(named: imageNamed)

          let tap =  UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped(sender: indexPath)))
          tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
          collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)   

          return subOptioncell
    }
}

func doubleTapped(sender: IndexPath) {
    print("Double Tap")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are adding tapGesture to `collectionView` instead of `subOptioncell`.

### It should be:

```
subOptioncell.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

### Instead of:

```
collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

You cannot pass other instance with `selector` of `UIGestureRecognizer`, the only instance you can pass is `UI(Tap)GestureRecognizer`. If you want the indexPath of that cell you can try like this. First of all set your `selector` of `TapGesture` like this.

```
let tap =  UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped(sender:)))
```

Now method should be like:

```
func doubleTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let cell = sender.view as? SubOptionsCollectionViewCell, let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) {
         print(indexPath)
    }       
}
```

**Edit:** If you want to show/hide image on cell double tap then you need to handle it using `indexPath` of cell, for that first declare one instance of `IndexPath` and use it inside `cellForItemAt indexPath`.

```
var selectedIndexPaths = IndexPath()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    //Your code 
    //Now add below code to handle show/hide image
    cell.subOptionSelected.isHidden = self.selectedIndexPaths != indexPath
    return cell
}
```

Now on `doubleTapped` action of `UITapGestureRecognizer` set the `selectedIndexPath`.

```
func doubleTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let cell = sender.view as? SubOptionsCollectionViewCell, let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) {
         if self.selectedIndexPaths == indexPath {
             cell.subOptionSelected.isHidden = true
             self.selectedIndexPaths = IndexPath()
         }
         else {
             cell.subOptionSelected.isHidden = false
             self.selectedIndexPaths = indexPath
         }           
    }       
}
```

Comment: But on scroll it gets hidden again. Strange need to debug.

Comment: @Nitesh I don't get it what you try to say, there is nothing like show or hide in your code.

Comment: I had kept button hidden in storyboard. Then I did `   func doubleTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if let cell = sender.view as? SubOptionsCollectionViewCell, let indexPath = self.subOptionsCollectionView.indexPath(for: cell) {
            print(indexPath)
            cell.subOptionSelected.isHidden = false
        }
        
    }`

Comment: I have a button which is hidden at first. When user doubleTaps the cell, I show that button. As if like a checkmark.

Comment: @Nitesh , You are adding TapGestureRegonizer method at cellForItemAtIndexPath. Please remove it and declare it at viewDidLoad() instead

Comment: @ThihaAung Read the question correctly OP want indexPath of tapped cell, so OP need to add gesture in cell not collectionView, so he is doing correctly now.

Comment: @NiravD Single cell. Only the one which is tapped twice.

Comment: @Nitesh Also if you tapped on hide image cell should it display it again?

Comment: If again double tap same cell again then button will be hidden.

Comment: @Nitesh I have already given answer like this check this one it will solved your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/41161101/6433023 In this answer i'm setting selected cell in didSelect instead of that you need to set it inside tapgesture action.

Comment: It works but I need it on doubleTap only. Earlier I had tried it in that way

Comment: Let me clear with your question. @Nitesh, you want to hide the button of the cell that you double tapped, am i correct?

Comment: No. See I have multiple images in my collection view. When user double taps a particular image, I display a tick symbol (i.e. button which is hidden at first). It is like selection a choice. We can tick only 1 from all.

Comment: @NiravD Yes thanks. It solved my problem. Thanks a lot. Good to learn :)

Comment: @Nitesh Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 1):

The correct selector in your case is `doubleTapped:`. That is

```
let tap =  UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped:))
```

You can not fire arbitrary parameter when the target method is called. You can set target on `subOptioncell` by

```
let tap =  UITapGestureRecognizer(target: subOptioncell, action: #selector(doubleTapped:))
```

And you can set whatever arbitrary object.parameter you want in `subOptioncell`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Selector like this way

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(YourViewControllerName.doubleTapped(_:)))
subOptioncell.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to.

```
let tap =  UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped(_:)))
```

and the function to.

```
func doubleTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Double Tap")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At your Datasource method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      if let subOptioncell : SubOptionsCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: subOptionsCVReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SubOptionsCollectionViewCell{
         //... your code
         subOptioncell.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
         return subOptioncell
       }

}
```

Then at the function `cellTapped()`

```
func cellTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    let tapLocation = sender.location(in: yourCollectionView)
    let indexPath : IndexPath = yourCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: tapLocation)!

    var currentIndex = 0

    if let cell = yourCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath){
        currentIndex = cell.tag
    }

    print("Your Selected Index : \(currentIndex)")
}
```

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: how you will get selected indexpath @cellTapped() ??

Comment: @DheerajD , my bad...forgot some code. I will fix it thanks

Comment: @ThihaAung Thank for help. Had already solved my problem with the ans posted by Nirav D

Comment: @Nitesh , Anytime