# Get indexPath of UICollectionView from UITable within

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I tried to implement a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to get the `indexPath.row` of the `collectionView` from a `tableView`.

I tried delegation too, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
protocol PassingCellDelegate {
    func passingIndexPath(passing: KitchenVC)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let tap =  UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapSwitchTableViewCollection))

    var delegate: PassingCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func buttonCompletedTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.passingIndexPath(passing: self)
    }

    func tapSwitchTableCollection(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if let cell = sender.view as? KitchenCollectionViewCell, let indexPath = collectionKitchen.indexPath(for: cell) {
        if self.selectedIndexPaths == indexPath {

            print("This in IF")
            print(indexPath)
            self.selectedIndexPaths = IndexPath()

        } else {

            print("This in ELSE")
            print(indexPath)
            self.selectedIndexPaths = indexPath

        }
    }
}
```

Cell class, where the `tableView` is contained in the CollectionViewCell

```
class CollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, PassingCellDelegate {

    func passingIndexPath(passing: KitchenVC) {

        passing.tapSwitchTableCollection(sender: passing.tap)

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OrdersCell")

        if tableView == ordersTableView {

            passingIndexPath(passing: KitchenVC())

        }

}
```

I got the method for `tapSwitchTableCollection` from this post:

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41259366/selector-to-get-indexpath-uicollectionview-swift-3-0"")!

Comment: do u have the collection view inside tableview ?

Comment: I have a tableView inside a collectionView, and would like to get the indexPath.row from the tableView inside of it. I cannot use didSelectItemAt from the collectionView because I want the tap to be fired from the tableView in didSelectRowAt

Comment: I had similar problem where i had a collectionView inside a tableView which is fairly the same.
If you are familiar for Objective C and i will show you some code how i achieved it without using gestures.
Please let me know if you are interested of me posting the answer.

Comment: Thank Florentt, but I managed to find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the right indexPath with this

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate { func passingIndexPath(passing: KitchenVC) }

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        var delegate: PassingCellDelegate?

        @IBAction func buttonCompletedTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
            delegate?.passingIndexPath(passing: self)
        }

        func completedTapped(cell: KitchenCollectionViewCell) {

            var thisIndex = collectionKitchen.indexPath(for: cell)
            currentIndex = (thisIndex?[1])!

            // This returns indexPath.row from the collectionView
        }
    }
```