# Passing parameter in UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift

So, I have a table with several rows.

Each row has it own gestureRecognizer, and in this gesture recognizer i want to pass as parameter the Int of the corresponding row so I can access to the data through a data array data[rownum].

How can I access to the Integer on the gesture recognizer GoToSendEmail?

This is the code i have now

```
var x = indexPath.row
        let gestureEdit = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                 action: #selector(self.GoToSendEmail(_:rowNum:))
                                                )
 cell.btnEdit.addGestureRecognizer(gestureEdit)
```

-

```
@objc func GoToSendEmail(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer, rowNum:Int)
{
    print("rownum:" + String(rowNum)) // rownum is always 0
    // data[rowNum] // this is the information i want
}
```

Comment: It won't be send. You can use `tag`. `cell.btnEdit.tag = indexPath.row`, and then `print("rownum:" + String(sender.tag))`.

Comment: I see that tag is an Integer, but what if i want to pass something more complex like MyRandomObject.

Comment: You use that into `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` no? So I guess, that you did `MyCustomObject *object = myArray[indexPath.row]; cell.something = object.somethingElse;`? Then, `MyCustomObject *object = myArray[tag]`

Comment: you can access gestureRecognizer.view which can be UITableViewCell or its subview. From there you can access the cell and check index of the cell in the tableview. Not a good solution, but will do the job for you. Also, as mentioned in the above comment you can set the tag for gestureRecognizer's view.

Comment: Possible Duplicate Of [Selector to get indexPath UICollectionView Swift 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41259366/selector-to-get-indexpath-uicollectionview-swift-3-0/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that easier with a target directly if your btnEdit is an UIButton.

```
cell.btnEdit.tag = indexPath.row
cell.btnEdit.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.editButtonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and the function

```
func editButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

   print(sender.tag) // your cell indexPath.row
   // or
   print(data[sender.tag])
}
```

Comment: not exactly what i was hoping but it does the trick :) thank you so much

Comment: with the gestureRecognizer it is the same approach. But you have an UIButton and only a TapGuestrure, so you can use the target.