# selector with argument gestureRecognizer

Tags: swift, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

> Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property,
>   or initializer

Problem : Above Error when i try to pass argument with selector 
code snippet:

```
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(labelPressed(i: 1)))

func labelPressed(i: Int){
        print(i)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selector to get indexPath UICollectionView Swift 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41259366/selector-to-get-indexpath-uicollectionview-swift-3-0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass a parameter to a function like that. Actions - which this is, only pass the sender, which in this case is the gesture recognizer. What you want to do is get the `UIView` you attached the gesture to:

```
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(labelPressed())

func labelPressed(_ recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let viewTapped = recognizer.view
}
```

A few more notes:

```
(1) You may only attach a single view to a recognizer.
(2) You might want to use both the `tag` property along with the `hitTest()` method to know which subview was hit. For example:


let view1 = UIView()
let view2 = UIView()

// add code to place things, probably using auto layout

view1.tag = 1
view2.tag = 2
mainView.addSubview(view1)
mainView.addSubview(view2)

let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(mainViewTapped())

func mainViewTapped(_ recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer){

    // get the CGPoint of the tap

    let p = recognizer.location(in: self)
    let viewTapped:UIView!

    // there are many (better) ways to do this, but this works

    for view in self.subviews as [UIView] {
        if view.layer.hitTest(p) != nil {
            viewTapped = view
        }
    }

    // if viewTapped != nil, you have your subview

}
```

Comment: you know how to animate the click ? Like button, when the color is changed fasted.

Answer (score 0):

You just should declare function like this:

```
@objc func labelPressed(i: Int){ print(i) }
```

Comment: Will this work? A gesture is the sender, not a UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Swift 3:

Using more modern syntax, you could declare your function like this:

```
@objc func labelTicked(withSender sender: AnyObject) {
```

and initialize your gesture recognizer like this, using #selector:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(labelTicked(withSender:)))
```